# Missing params when updating only single attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like the site's admin to be able to update permissions for users. My `user` model has an attribute `permissions_id` which is simply an integer that doesn't even relate to another table, just a number I'll reference later.

The error I'm getting is `param is missing or the value is empty: user` when going to the `users/:id/choose_permissions` URL. I figured that the rest of the user's information will be passed to the controller when it tries to update the user, but it doesn't see the user I'm passing it.

I've tried switching the params to `params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(...)` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22444337/3251199) but it just skips over the form whenever I go to `users/:id/choose_permissions`.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def choose_permissions
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "User updated"
    redirect_to @user 
  else
    render 'update_permissions'
  end
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                 :password_confirmation, :permissions_id)
  end
```

**app/views/users/choose_permissions.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label "Choose permissions" %>
  <%= f.password_field :permissions_id, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :choose_permissions
  end
end
```

Is it because this page is a `GET` request instead of a `PATCH`? Or is it possibly because an admin is trying to update another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your controller, you should split the edit and update actions this way:

```
def edit_choose_permissions
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update_choose_permissions
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "User updated"
    redirect_to @user 
  else
    render 'edit_update_permissions'
  end
end
```

As you are not following REST, you should specify the url in your form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: update_choose_permissions_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

Also for your routes, you'll have to rewrite them this way:

```
get 'users/:id/choose_permissions, to: 'users#edit_choose_permissions', as: 'edit_choose_permissions'
patch 'users/:id/choose_permissions, to: 'users#update_choose_permissions', as: 'update_choose_permissions'
```

Disclaimer: not tested.

Comment: I think the `url` parameter needs to go inside the parenthesis, otherwise I get a syntax error. But even when I use the correct syntax, it says it can't find the method `update_choose_permissions`.

Comment: Would it be easiest to just allow the admin to edit the other users and just show a form for that one option? This current method doesn't seem very clean.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the `path`part of the url. Edited.

On the other hand, I also think that it's not the best way to update a param but I don't have enough info of your problem to give you other advice. I think it should work with this edit anyway.

Comment: Short version: User signs up, admin gets email of new user, admin assigns permissions to user, user free to use site. Thoughts? This did answer my question though, so thanks!

Comment: I think I'll stick with the current technique, but I'll keep this in mind. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Try to keep always into REST, using new and update actions. Almost 90% of time there is no need of using custom actions.

Comment: Might as well start good habits now. I'll work on generating a `permissions` model and linking it to my `users` model. Thanks.